# Impersonation for Local Machine Succeeding when it should fail

Tags: c#, impersonation

The problem:

I have windows service that uses impersonation to check the service status on a separate server, however it was noted during testing that when the user supplied a local machine address and an invalid local machine account the check would proceed to open the service control manager and retrieve the status successfully. We aim to have it only work with a valid local machine account.

The Code:
Impersonation namespace (contains method (SoddingNetworkAuth) used to set up the impersonation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Impersonation
{
  public class Network
  {
    public class SoddingNetworkAuth : IDisposable
    {
      [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);
      [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
      private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
      private IntPtr userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
      private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
      public SoddingNetworkAuth(string user, string domain, string password)
      {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
          // Call LogonUser to get a token for the user  
          bool loggedOn = LogonUser(user, domain, password,
                          9 /*(int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS*/,
                          3 /*(int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50*/,
          out userHandle);
          if (!loggedOn)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
          // Begin impersonating the user  
          impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);
        }
      }
      public void Dispose()
      {
        if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
          CloseHandle(userHandle);
        if (impersonationContext != null)
          impersonationContext.Undo();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A console app I wrote for the test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace NetworkAuthIssue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                using (new Impersonation.Network.SoddingNetworkAuth("Invalid User", "localhost", "InvalidPassword"))
                {
                    var serviceController = new ServiceController("Power", "localhost");
                    if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                    {
                        result = "Authenticated, service running";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = "Authenticated, service not running";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = "Authentication Failed";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS`.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (emphasis mine):

> This logon type allows the caller to clone its current token and specify new credentials for **outbound connections**. The new logon session has the same local identifier but uses different credentials for other network connections.

The "outbound connections" part is important. It means that for local connections, the provided credentials aren't used at all. The current identity gets used for local connections.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check things right now but I had similar issues like you and this was caused by the selected LogonType/LogonProvider values in the Logon method. You should try them out in a console app and use the combination which works for your scenario.

See also the msdn documentation for this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx